# Realm object notification for every object in realm

Tags: swift, dictionary, realm

I'm creating a sync manager for my app and part of that process is to track changes made in the local Realm and queue them for upload to the server. As far as I can tell, collection notifications lack some important details for this case, such as missing the `primaryKey` of an object that has been deleted. They also send notifications when a property has been changed on a related object, which is not the behavior I want when tracking changes to sync.

The library [SyncKit](https://github.com/mentrena/SyncKit) manages change tracking by iterating through every object in the Realm and adding an object notification to a dictionary `[String: NotificationToken]` where the object `id` is the dictionary key. This seems reasonable, but I'm wondering if there are any performance limitations to this approach based on the implementation of `NotificationToken` under the hood.

What happens if 1000 objects are deleted at the same time? Is it reasonable to store 20,000 objects in the Realm, each with their own `NotificationToken`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need think of when you data can be changed. For example, you creating an object => trigger SERVER API request. Then, user edited some object => trigger request on object update. User deleted some object -> do the same thing. I didn't used `SyncKit`, so i don't know exact features it can do. But holding 10k references on notification changes... It doesn't seem to be reasonable